# When using number in url it is redircting to same page but when using character it redirects to 404

Tags: permalinks, urls, htaccess, 404-error

I have a website e.g abc.com in wordpress, when I enter any url like abc.com/blog/1232132 then it is redirecting to the same url and showing the content of abc.com/blog but when I am using urls like abc.com/blog/dasdas then it is giving 404 page.

I saw in so many websites of wordpress.

How to fix that so that if I use any wrong url it should take me to 404 page

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress website, if you enter number like ABC.com/blog/1232132 then it will redirect to the same page because this number are not come under any category of the permalink.

So that when you enter this kind of URL then it will redirect to its current page.

Comment: so its not possible to redirect these extra urls to 404